# react-apollo: Long running mutation appears to be retried after 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, graphql, react-apollo

I have a long running import script (~4 minutes) which is kicked off with a graphql mutation.  Logging on the server, I've noticed that exactly 2 minutes after I trigger the mutation, it gets retried, causing the import to be run twice.

I guess this is caused by some functionality in `apollo-link` but I've had a look through the code there and can't find an option to turn it off.

Here is how I've set up apollo:

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import config from 'src/config'
import { getItem } from 'src/utils/local-store'

const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: config.graphql })
const middlewareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  const token = getItem(config.jwtKey)
  if (token) {
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })
  }
  return forward(operation)
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: middlewareLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(window.__APOLLO_STATE__ || {})
})

export default client
```

There is nothing fancy going on in the mutation itself:

```
export class ReleaseImport extends PureComponent {

  // ...

  handleSaveRelease = async () => {
    const { save, artistId } = this.props
    const { id, releaseGroupId } = this.state
    await save({ variables: { release: { id, releaseGroupId }, artistId } })
  }

  // ...

}

const saveArtistRelease = gql`
  mutation ImportSaveArtistRelease($release: ImportReleaseInput!, $artistId: Int!) {
    importSaveArtistRelease(release: $release, artistId: $artistId) {
      id
    }
  }
`

export default compose(
  graphql(saveArtistRelease, {
    name: 'save'
  })
)(ReleaseImport)
```

Just looking to turn off this retry functionality. Thanks.

Comment: Does your mutation works at your Graphqil? Why are your using compose, you can use only graphql higher order component. If you had two or more higher order components you should use compose.

Comment: @AlessanderFrança I have more things going on in the component that I removed cause they're not relevant to this.  I haven't tried in Graphiql but the mutation does work as expected, it just gets retried after 2 minutes and runs twice.

Comment: Can you add more information of your component? Like the render and where handleSaveRelease is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was barking up the wrong tree.

It turns out node's default timeout is 2 minutes, and if it does get to the 2 minutes, it WILL retry the request.

In my case, using Koa, the fix was simply:

```
// make timeout value 5 minutes
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.req.setTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000)
  await next()
})
```